# 404 error in rewrite htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this in my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^subdir/([^/.]*)/?/([_A-Za-z0-9-]+).html/?$ index.php?action=subdir&stateid=$1
RewriteRule ^subdir/([_A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?action=subdir&title=$1stateid=$1&full=yes
```

But, when I receive only this

```
mysite/subdir
```

then Apache translates to this

```
mysite/subdir/.html
```

and I get a 404 error.

How can I catch this case for redirect to index.php?

I tried this

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.html$ index.php [L]
```

but it didn't work either.

Comment: Why use a bunch of rewrites? Why not just rewrite everything to index.php, then parse the URL in PHP and do what you need all in one place?

Comment: I don't see anywhere that a `.html` could be written, are you sure you don't have any other RewriteRules somewhere?

Comment: animuson , I agree with you but this is a legacy system and now is a litle hard change this.

Comment: Jon Lin, Exist more things in this htaccess but only in this  rows I have this specific subdir. I debug in index.php and the request dont call it. The server redirect to 404 page.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with /subdir, for example a `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html` somewhere will cause that ".html" thing to get appended to /subdir/